# Will python mysql connection pool keep connections?

Tags: python, mysql

If you use `mysql.connector.connect` to connect to mysql database, the connection will be automatically disconnected after 8 hours. My question is: if I use mysql connection pool to connect to mysql database, so that means I can always get a useable connection and no need to worry about the 8 hours limit?

Comment: The automatic disconnect is probably from the server's idle timer, not related to the connector library.

Comment: Does your pool test connections before issuing them?

Comment: @tadman I don't know. I just use the pool, and I hope the pool will automatically create a connection if not available.

Comment: The problem here is not a lack of connections, it's connections that are no longer valid for whatever reason. A good connection pool will periodically check that they're still active instead of assuming they're fine in perpetuity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Barmar for direction, I read an article: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-change-connection-timeout-in-mysql/. The default timeout is 28800 (8 hours). We can use a mysql command to set the idle time to as long as we want, for example:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SET SESSION wait_timeout = 864000")
```

Then you will never need to worry about connection lost, unless you did not send any command in 10 days. Maybe it's not a good idea, but I want it to keep connection for at least 10 days. Hope it can help someone else.

Comment: You CANNOT assume that your connection will live forever.  There are miscellaneous internet interruptions all the time, both locally within your own network, and globally in the big wide world.  And as soon as you code for that, the timeout is irrelevant.  Code defensively -- don't assume.